# Raspbian .NET Core 2.0 Manifest not found

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, raspbian

Install on R PI3 with Raspbian .NET Core 2.0

dotnet --info:

```
Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host

  Version  : 2.0.4
  Build    : 7f262f453d8c8479b9af91d34c013b3aa05bc1ff
```

Created in Visual Studio 2017 simple App:

**Program.cs:**

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseUrls("http://*:5000") // Using * to bind to all network interfaces
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();

    host.Run();
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
        });
    }
}
```

**.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>false</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

When run program on Pi :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ dotnet /home/pi/netcoreapp2.0/WebApplication2.dll
Error:
  An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (WebApplication2.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore', version: '2.1.1'
    path: 'lib/netstandard1.6/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.dll'
```

Why do I receive an error?

Comment: I don't understand. I make a console application шт VS 2017 and can execute on Rpi it. Is there a problem?

Comment: Does `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.dll` exist in `lib/netstandard1.6`?

Comment: I could not dotnet 1.6 on my RPI. Pi has an ARMFL processor, and not the ARM64 in the list of versions is not always clearly specified.